# Better code for find and update item in multiple list c#

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I'm curious is there any other approach for finding an item in multiple lists with different classes by `Id` and to update it rather then writing three if statements.

**In short:**
I have `entity` object that contains list of `Rules`, but however, I need foreach rule in `Rules` object to iterate and check if that rule corresponds to some of this three lists which have `Id` and if does, to update some property called `Order`

Also I need to collect all rules from `entity.Rules`object that does not correposnd to any of these lists (not found)
My solution for the first part goes like this:

```
ClassFoo entity = GetData();
companyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules = existingCompanyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules; //IEnumerable<ClassA>
companyPolicy.ExceptionRules = existingCompanyPolicy.ExceptionRules; //IEnumerable<ClassB>
companyPolicy.AmountOfHoursRules = existingCompanyPolicy.AmountOfHoursRules; //IEnumerable<ClassC>

foreach (var rule in entity.Rules)
{
    if (companyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules.Any(x => x.Id == rule.Id))
    {
        var existingRule = existingCompanyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == rule.Id);
        existingRule.Order = rule.Order;
    }

    if (companyPolicy.ExceptionRules.Any(x => x.Id == rule.Id))
    {
        var existingRule = existingCompanyPolicy.ExceptionRules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == rule.Id);
        existingRule.Order = rule.Order;
    }

    if (companyPolicy.AmountOfHoursRules.Any(x => x.Id == rule.Id))
    {
        var existingRule = existingCompanyPolicy.AmountOfHoursRules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == rule.Id);
        existingRule.Order = rule.Order;
    }
}

// do union of different lists of classes
//  companyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules
//  companyPolicy.ExceptionRules
//  companyPolicy.AmountOfHoursRules

//get objects from Rules that does not corresponds to any of these lists (not found in any of lists)

//each list has Id object, and I need to find item in all three lists and to update it
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify your checks by using pattern matching:

```
if(companyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == rule.Id) is { } existingRule)
{
    existingRule.Order = rule.Order;
}
```

To simplify checking all lists you would need some common interface that all the objects in the lists share. If you have that it should be as simple as creating a loop over all lists. If there is no common interface you will need three separate checks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Any` checks are redundant. Just get `FirstOrDefault` and if it's not `null` you know that there is a match ;)

And to your second problem: create an empty list and add the rules that have no matches.

```
ClassFoo entity = GetData();
companyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules = existingCompanyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules; //IEnumerable<ClassA>
companyPolicy.ExceptionRules = existingCompanyPolicy.ExceptionRules; //IEnumerable<ClassB>
companyPolicy.AmountOfHoursRules = existingCompanyPolicy.AmountOfHoursRules; //IEnumerable<ClassC>

var notFoundInAnyOfLists = new List<ClassRule>();

foreach (var rule in entity.Rules)
{
    var exceptionRule = existingCompanyPolicy.ExceptionRules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == rule.Id);
    var amountOfHoursRule = existingCompanyPolicy.AmountOfHoursRules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == rule.Id);
    var automaticPunchRule = existingCompanyPolicy.AutomaticPunchRules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == rule.Id);

    if (automaticPunchRule is null && exceptionRule is null && amountOfHoursRule is null)
    {
        notFoundInAnyOfLists.Add(rule);
        continue; // no point in doing the three checks
    }

    if (automaticPunchRule is not null)
    {
        automaticPunchRule.Order = rule.Order;
    }

    if (exceptionRule is not null)
    {
        exceptionRule.Order = rule.Order;
    }

    if (amountOfHoursRule is not null)
    {
        amountOfHoursRule.Order = rule.Order;
    }
}
```